# How could you relate arbitrary models using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, relational-database

Let's say I have

```
class Notification
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :noteworthy, type: Boolean, default: true
    # some kind of relation to a source
    before_create :remove_noise

    def remove_noise
        notification = Notification.last
        if notification.source_id == self.source_id
            notification.update_attribute(:noteworthy, false)
        end 
    end
end
```

is there some way to do this where a notification's source could be one of any mongoid::document models?

The use case:

I want to create a notification center that only shows noteworthy notifications, meaning those originating from distinct models.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand the question, can u expand more on it?

Answer (score 0):

hum, interesting, relation to arbitrary model.

Well the way I would go about it is to make it not arbitrary at all.

```
class Notification
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :noteworthy, type: Boolean, default: true
  has_one :source
end

class Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to, :notification
  # stuff
end

class Webpage < Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  # stuff
end

class Facebook < Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  # stuff
end

class Twitter < Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  # stuff
end
```

This way, has_one source could be a webpage, twitter or facebook model since they each inherit  from the source class. add the custom fields and methods in Webpage, Twitter, Facebook and try to keep it DRY by moving duplicate methods and fields into the source model.

Comment: would source need a belongs_to ?

Comment: yep, of course, this is just the idea behind it, you may need to use  has_and_belongs_to_many